# Remove links from meta widget

Tags: widgets

I've had my wordpress page hosted in a free host. This host added some code in exchange of the free service, like two links to their free and paid services webpages into my `Meta` widget.

For me it was ok at that time, but finally I moved my page to a VPS. I **exported** everything with `All-in-One WP Migration` widget, and **imported** it in the new host.

So the problem is that these links from my previous free host have appeared again in my `Meta` widget in the new host, due to the import that I've performed.

So basically, **how can I remove them**? **How can I edit the Meta widget**? I've tried to do it from the Desktop but I found no way to do it, so I guess it should be done directly modifying the file of the plugin... but I don't know which one it is.

Comment: Why don't you just use a text widget instead?

Comment: A screenshot or link would be helpful.

Comment: @HowardE because this is not the only thing that the previous hosting changed inside the code of wordpress, it has also some other modifications, and I would like to purge them all

Comment: @Karun www.btcsources.es

Comment: There could be a plugin or function in your theme that has hooked into `wp_meta`. Look for `add_action` which has triggered `wp_meta`. Start with your theme function files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things you can do here. If you do not want to touch the source code, install any meta widget plugin editor (example - https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-meta-widget/) and make required changes.

If you can access your code, then look for default-widget.php file, find the lines where you have the unnecessary links, delete them and save the file. Please keep a backup copy of the file before you try this.